# Android: Get Data From Inserted Contact

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

Using this line of code:

```
Intent addContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
addContact.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,"09876543210");
startActivity(addContact);
```

I was able to launch the Android's insert contact activity with a default contact number on it.

Now, using the defined intent above, how can I construct a `startActivityForResult` so that I can get the inputted contact details (First name, Last Name etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Why start activity for result..? From your question I am getting that you want to create application which takes contact details from user and adds it as news contact to the contact list. You can achieve this using following code...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
private EditText mEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
private EditText mPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);

 intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, mEmailAddress.getText())
.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, mPhoneNumber.getText())
.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
```

Once you've created the Intent, send it by calling startActivity().

```
startActivity(intent);
```

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) 
and [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) for more options.

Comment: it seems that your answer has the same effect on my intent except that it has a default value for the contact name. What if the user changed the default contact name? I dont think it will update the values in `mEmailAddress` field.

Comment: what I want is to get the value in the first name field after the user has submitted the form in the new contact

Comment: Is this what you want:
 

`private EditText mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);`


`intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME.mUserName.getText());`


[Check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html)